# Spring security for REST api without web.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, web.xml

I am fairly new to Spring, so please bear with me. I followed a getting started tutorial [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

So what I have currently is a web project in Eclipse, where I can create methods with `@RequestMapping`, and handle particular paths and requestparams/pathparams.
 I don't have a `web.xml`, I only have `Application.java` with the following code in the `main` method and no annotations etc:

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

For now, this works fine. However I would like to implement some security to restrict access to certain parts of my API. More specifically, there will be many 'event' objects (think Wedding, birthday.. etc). Each user may have a role on that event, e.g Bride, Groom, Brithday girl, guest. Alice may be the birthday girl of event 1, the bride of event 2, and not related to event 3.

Only if a particular role is held should they be able to get information about that event. I have seen lots of security configurations with simple roles, but here the role depends on the event. I also do not have a `web.xml`, which most of the others refer to, so I'm struggling to get started. I don't know if Spring Security is the way forwards for this.

As i'm new to this, any pointers in the right direction would be great. I have implemented a connection to a database using Hibernate, which this is to work with, and I can create a "custom" solution, but I think i'm missing something and perhaps reinventing the wheel. My current solution is to create a `AuthHandler`, which I call directly from my methods in the controllers annotated with `@RequestMapping`, with a event ID and username/password passed in through the `Authorization` header which returns an enum `Role`. Is there a better way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **tl;dr** Have a look in [this post series covering REST APIs](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-with-spring-series/)

---

Take a look in https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/#initial, since you are using Spring Boot and the guides, this part shows how to build a basic security but also you can expand them to your roles like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/buffet")
                .hasAnyRole("BRIDE","GROOM","BDAY")
                .antMatchers("/andSoOn").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

And if you want to save user and roles in database ("of course you want") have a look in `UserDetails` and `UserDetailsService` have a look in this example in [Rob Winch's github repo](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-0-to-4.0/blob/master/src/main/java/sample/security/UserRepositoryUserDetailsService.java), the project leader of Spring Security, which can point you to the right direction, you also need to implement some kind of matcher for authorities, so you load the user, get its authorities, matches with a static list, then it will build the authorizations

If you want protection on method/class/controller level you can annotate the configuration class with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`, this one will enable the `@PreAuthorize('hasAnyRole("FOO")')` and
`@PostAuthorize('hasAnyRole("FOO")')`

You can also have "in-memory" users configuring in the same class:

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
              .withUser("lovelyOne").password("hothusband").roles("BRIDE");
    }
```

And some docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration) to you follow up

PS: You don't need to relay only on `permitAll(String)` and `hasAnyRole(String)` you also have, `hasRole(String)`,`isAuthenticated` `#authenticated()` `#anonymous`, as far I rembember